# 2 web views with button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

Hi guys I am really new in xcode, I am using
xcode 5.1  my project has a view like principal view, this view has 6 buttons 2 of them open a webView, searching in internet I found examples about how to open a single web view, but my problem is that i need open more than 1 web view, maybe my question is stupid... but How can I open 2 webViews with buttons click?

this is my code

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *supWebView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *serviciosWebView;
- (IBAction)servicios:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)support:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize supWebView;
@synthesize serviciosWebView;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [super viewDidLoad];
    //aki para que funcione uno
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (IBAction)support:(id)sender{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxx.xx/conectar.html"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [supWebView loadRequest:requestURL];
}
- (IBAction)servicios:(id)sender {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxx.xx/servicios.html"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [serviciosWebView loadRequest:requestURL];
}

@end
```

I do not know if I need to declare something in app delegate, I follow some tutorials and it says that it does not need. I am connecting my buttons with push to go to another view.

Can some one guide me please? y.y

Comment: Use webView with different tag. And check tag value in webview delegate method do your appropriate task or function.

Comment: sorry, Could you be more specific please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this right (2 webviews, each loading different URLs on separate button actions), you're calling loadRequest on the wrong webView for servicios. Your servicios: method should be as follows:

```
- (IBAction)servicios:(id)sender {   
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://xxxxx.xxxx/servicios.html"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [serviciosWebView loadRequest:requestURL];   
}
```

Comment: Thank you for tell me about my error, but my web view still is not working, when I run the project it open the first view with the 6 buttons, when I click some of the 2 buttons it open a new View(with the web view) but my webView does not show nothing.

Comment: Did you connect the outlet in interface builder? Do you invoke the support: or servicios: methods anywhere? They're IBActions, does the user press a button when ViewController is displayed, or are you wanting the web views to load the url on load? Put a breakpoint in support: and servicios:. Do the methods execute?